# Any class or API for iOS Notes app to retrive notes and edit notes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to retrive all notes from iOS native notes app and do operations on it and save natively. Is there any class or API for that?

Comment: There is no API for that.

Comment: Okay...Thanks @Avi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no public API or classes for this in iOS SDK.

To checkout the complete list of new features you can visit the Apple Document on [What's new in iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html).

To see all the API changes from iOS 8 to 9, visit [iOS 9.0 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016222)